# How does primefaces bind selection values to bean?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Here the code from the primefaces datatable component:

```
public void setSelection(java.lang.Object _selection) {
        getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.selection, _selection);
}
```

I tried to copy it to my component, but it doesn't add values to my bean.

Comment: Do you want to grab the selected list of rows in a corresponding managed bean? A source code xerox copy is not required for that. There are relevant examples on the PrimeFaces showcase.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code in the datatable that binds values to bean

```
@Override
public void processUpdates(FacesContext context) {
    super.processUpdates(context);

    ValueExpression selectionVE = this.getValueExpression("selection");

    if(selectionVE != null) {
        selectionVE.setValue(context.getELContext(), this.getLocalSelection());

        this.setSelection(null);
    }
```

Comment: why is this the answer? What was your original **problem**